# How to make InetAddress.reachable() execute faster?

Tags: android, kotlin, inet

In my app i'm trying to get list of connected device to wifi here i can successfully fetch all device but issue is the entire process is taking a lot of time to execute here when i remove  `val reachable = address.isReachable(1000)` from my loop it gets executed instantly but however i need this line of code to check for connection so my question is how can enhance my code to achieve desired results faster!

Any suggestions will be appreciated!

Here's is my code:

```
for (i in 0..254)
                    {
                        val testIp = prefix + (i).toString()
                        val address = InetAddress.getByName(testIp)
                        val reachable = address.isReachable(1000)
                        val hostName = address.hostName.toString()
                        if (reachable) {
                            Log.i(TAG, "Host: " + (hostName) + "(" + (testIp) + ") is Connected!")
                        }

                    }
```

This is my full code to fetch list of connected devices:

```
fun sniffnetwork(){
        val mContextRef:WeakReference<Context>
        mContextRef = WeakReference<Context>(this)
        Observable.fromCallable {
            Log.d(TAG, "Let's sniff the network")
            try
            {
                val context = mContextRef.get()
                if (context != null)
                {
                    val cm = context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE) as ConnectivityManager
                    val activeNetwork = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo()
                    val wm = context.getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE) as WifiManager
                    val connectionInfo = wm.getConnectionInfo()
                    val ipAddress = connectionInfo.getIpAddress()
                    val ipString = Formatter.formatIpAddress(ipAddress)
                    Log.d(TAG, "activeNetwork: " + activeNetwork.toString())
                    wifiname = activeNetwork.extraInfo
                    wifiname= wifiname.replace("^\"|\"$".toRegex(), "")
                    tvwifiname.text = wifiname + " "+ "connected "
                    Log.d(TAG, "ipString: " + (ipString).toString())
                    val prefix = ipString.substring(0, ipString.lastIndexOf(".") + 1)
                    Log.d(TAG, "prefix: " + prefix)
                    for (i in 0..254)
                    {
                        val testIp = prefix + (i).toString()
                        val address = InetAddress.getByName(testIp)
                        val reachable = address.isReachable(200)
                        val hostName = address.hostName.toString()
                        if (reachable) {
                            Log.i(TAG, "Host: " + (hostName) + "(" + (testIp) + ") is Connected!")
                        }

                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    Log.i("error:","Context is null")
                }
            }
            catch (t:Throwable) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Well that's not good.", t)
            }

        }.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribe{

                }
    }
```

Comment: why do you do it in a for loop? this would run 255 times even though it is reachable, the check is already a slow blocking call

Comment: Then what should i do? i am not check only one ip i'm checking for all ip's from 0 to 254 wait i'll post my full code